# ZendDebugger on Ubuntu server

Tags: eclipse, debugging, zend-framework, ubuntu-server

I like to debug my PHP applications. So, I installed the ZendDebugger.
I downloaded and placed the `ZendDebugger.so` file in

```
/usr/lib/php5/modules/ZendDebugger.so
```

And pasted this code in the `php.ini` file:

```
zend_extension=/usr/lib/php5/modules/ZendDebugger.so
```

This path is correct, and I have tried several other paths.

I also have tried other codes in the `php.ini` file.

I work with a Ubuntu server and eclipse with the PDT extension on Ubuntu.

But the debugger is not installed. The only information I can find in the phpinfo is:

> This program makes use of the Zend Scripting Language Engine:
>   Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2011 Zend Technologies

I don't know what to do? I have searched many times on the internet, and tied it with a clean server install.

Comment: Did you restart the server after making the change to `php.ini`?  If so, try enabling the `php.ini` setting `display_startup_errors` and `display_errors` and then restart the server.  Then load a PHP page and see if there is an error that shows up saying it failed to load that module.  Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. My server don't works at the moment.

Comment: No, it still don't work, and it doesn't give any errors.

Comment: Is the right `php.ini` file being edited?  In phpinfo(), it should say which file is the correct `php.ini` for the web server.

Comment: Yes thath's correct, I also restart the apache2 server after editing the php.ini file. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Did you compile PHP yourself or are you using a version installed by a package manager?  The only other thing I can think is that maybe you accidentally copied the wrong Zend Debugger version for the version of PHP you have, or maybe you are using the 32 bit version with 64 bit PHP or vice-versa.

Comment: Oh and you aren't using PHP 5.4 correct?

Comment: Thanks aigain for the help. I think I'm using 5.3.6. I have installed the lamp-server^, in this package the PHP package is included. I'm using a 64bit server, I will check the version I have downloaded.